# Tuple of strings to sqlite column

Tags: python, sqlite

How would you insert a tuple of strings to a sql column? At the moment I concatenate the strings in the tuple with a token and then when I read out the value again I split on this token.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) (or cPickle) module, it's probably easier than rolling your own code:

```
import pickle

my_tuple = ('one', 'two', 'three')
pickle.dumps(my_tuple)  # <-- insert that into DB
```

to read it out, just pull the string out of the DB and call:

```
my_reconstituted_tuple = pickle.loads(data_from_db)
```